# How to create a deep copy of an object in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, object, copy, deep-copy

I did some searching found some different methods and posts about creating a deep copy operator.

Is there a quick and easy (built-in) way to deep copy objects in Ruby? The fields are not arrays or hashes.

Working in Ruby 1.9.2.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14104542/ruby-object-deep-copying

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Deep copy isn't built into vanilla Ruby, but you can hack it by marshalling and unmarshalling the object:

```
Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(@object))
```

This isn't perfect though, and won't work for all objects. A more robust method:

```
class Object
  def deep_clone
    return @deep_cloning_obj if @deep_cloning
    @deep_cloning_obj = clone
    @deep_cloning_obj.instance_variables.each do |var|
      val = @deep_cloning_obj.instance_variable_get(var)
      begin
        @deep_cloning = true
        val = val.deep_clone
      rescue TypeError
        next
      ensure
        @deep_cloning = false
      end
      @deep_cloning_obj.instance_variable_set(var, val)
    end
    deep_cloning_obj = @deep_cloning_obj
    @deep_cloning_obj = nil
    deep_cloning_obj
  end
end
```

Source:

http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-list/43424

Comment: OK, thanks. I found a post about marshalling but didn't know if it was a reasonable solution. `Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(@object))` worked great.

Comment: Yeah, it's only slow relatively speaking - you'd only notice if you were cloning lots of objects at a time

Comment: Obviously, it also assumes that the object is marshallable in the first place, which not all objects are.

Comment: How comes and there isn't any ruby built in method for that?

Answer (score 20):

I've created a native implementation to perform deep clones of ruby objects.

It's approximately 6 to 7 times faster than the Marshal approach.

https://github.com/balmma/ruby-deepclone

Note that this project is not maintained anymore (last commit in [2017](https://github.com/gmodarelli/ruby-deepclone/commits/master), there are reported [issues](https://github.com/gmodarelli/ruby-deepclone/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+sort%3Aupdated-desc))

Comment: This project is not maintained any more and not production ready, according to the author.

Answer (score 7):

There is a native implementation to perform deep clones of ruby objects: [ruby_deep_clone](http://rubygems.org/gems/ruby_deep_clone)

Install it with gem:

```
gem install ruby_deep_clone
```

Example usage:

```
require "deep_clone"
object = SomeComplexClass.new()
cloned_object = DeepClone.clone(object)
```

It's approximately 6 to 7 times faster than the Marshal approach and event works with frozen objects.

Note that this project is not maintained anymore (last commit in [2017](https://github.com/gmodarelli/ruby-deepclone/commits/master), there are reported [issues](https://github.com/gmodarelli/ruby-deepclone/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+sort%3Aupdated-desc))

Comment: Unfortunately, this gem does not handle custom Collection classes that inherit from Array and contain their own complex nested classes.

Ruby_deep_clone turns those objects into Arrays and they lose their custom attributes.

Comment: This project is not maintained any more and not production ready, according to the author.

Comment: @bbozo It claims to support up to Ruby 2.4. Is there a source saying it is no longer maintained?

Comment: This answer is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8206523/how-to-create-a-deep-copy-of-an-object-in-ruby/15875069#15875069 that was posted earlier

Answer (score 7):

Rails has a recursive method named `deep_dup` that will return a deep copy of an object and, on the contrary of `dup` and `clone`, works even on composite objects (array/hash of arrays/hashes).
It's as easy as:

```
def deep_dup
  map { |it| it.deep_dup }
end
```

Comment: Rails' Object#deep_dup is actually a shallow `dup` call. Besdie Hash and Array, you need to implement your own `deep_dup` for it to work.

Answer (score 3):

You can use duplicate gem for this.

It's a small pure ruby gem that able to recursively duplicate object
It will duplicate it's object references too to the new duplication.

```
require 'duplicate'
duplicate('target object')
```

https://rubygems.org/gems/duplicate

https://github.com/adamluzsi/duplicate.rb

Answer (score 3):

Automatic deep clone is not always what you want. Often you need to define a selected few attributes to deep clone. A flexible way to do this is to implement the `initialize_copy`, `initialize_dup` and `initialize_clone` methods.

If you have a class:

```
class Foo
  attr_accessor :a, :b
end
```

and you only want to only deep clone `:b`, you override the `initialize_*` method:

```
class Foo
  attr_accessor :a, :b

  def initialize_dup(source)
    @b = @b.dup
    super
  end
end
```

Of course if you want `@b` to also deep clone some of its own attributes, you do the same in b's class.

Rails does this (see https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/0951306ca5edbaec10edf3440d5ba11062a4f2e5/activemodel/lib/active_model/errors.rb#L78)

For more complete explanation, I learned it here from this post https://aaronlasseigne.com/2014/07/20/know-ruby-clone-and-dup/

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you use the ActiveSupport gem which adds a lot of sugar to your native Ruby core, not just a [deep clone](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#deep-dup) method.

You can look into the [documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/activesupport/4.2.3) for more information regarding the methods that have been added.

Answer (score 2):

You really don't need a Gem for this.  This couldn't be much simpler than this, which is not worth the overhead of a Gem!

```rb
def deep_clone(obj)
  obj.clone.tap do |new_obj|
    new_obj.each do |key, val|
      new_obj[key] = deep_clone(val) if val.is_a?(Hash)
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Also check out deep_dive. This allows you to do controlled deep copies of your object graphs.

https://rubygems.org/gems/deep_dive