# Deep copy of collection containing proc objects

Tags: ruby

I need to make a deep copy of an object.
The only way I know to make a deep copy
of an object is with the following:

```
Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(my_object))
```

To my dismay, I found that if some element
of the object being deep copied is a proc object
then I get an error because proc objects don't
have a dump method and can't be deep copied that
way.

How do I make a deep copy of an object with
procs in them?

Comment: Different variants of this question exist but they are either too general or too specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A deep copy in Ruby using `clone` should do the trick. (Marshalling won't work for some objects... and it makes sense if Procs fall into that category).

`clone` is a convention that means deep copy, even though deep copies aren't supported in Ruby out of the box. However, [an answer on SO to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8206523/how-to-create-a-deep-copy-of-an-object-in-ruby) has a really good, generic, implementation of `clone`

Comment: According to the Object class docs for 1.9.3 clone means shallow copy. I probably don't understand, are you talking about something else?

Comment: Using `clone` is more of a community convention for deep copy. I agree the docs for `Object#clone` are... not obvious about this. Regardless, you may be able to avoid the whole situation (if you don't like the whole situation) by using `deep_copy` in that SO question I linked to

Comment: I don't agree that #clone is a "community convention for deep copy".  Neither is #dup.  Actually both state in their contract that they are shallow copies.  People have certainly undertaken to implement deep copy via #dup and #clone but there is certainly not a community convention that I am aware of.  I guess it totally depends on the circumstances what approaches are taken.  In my experience deep copying is rarely needed anyway.  I have the expression that there is a smell of cargo cult programming around deep copying...