# Ruby - passing by value

Tags: ruby, object

Is there a way to pass objects by value and not by reference in Ruby? For Example,

```
class Person
  attr_accessor :name
end
def get_name(obj)
  obj.name = "Bob"
  puts obj.name
end
jack = Person.new
jack.name = "Jack"
puts jack.name
get_name(jack)
puts jack.name
```

the output should be

```
Jack
Bob
Jack
```

instead of

```
Jack
Bob
Bob
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you have to create a new object, copy the name, pass the object to the function. Having said that it's rarely needed. Most likely to redesign the function is better solution.

Comment: Is there an underlying problem you are trying to solve, or are you just trying to learn more about Ruby?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No.** Ruby [passes by reference, not value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1872110/is-ruby-pass-by-reference-or-by-value).

If you need to simulate passing by value, you can use Ruby's `Object#clone` method. In this case, you'd do something like this:

```
def get_name(obj)
  new_object = obj.clone
  new_object.name = "Bob"
  puts new_object.name
end
```

This makes a **shallow copy** of an object. In other words, an object's instance variables are copied, but the objects the variables reference aren't copied. If you need to do a **deep copy**, you can read [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8206523/how-to-create-a-deep-copy-of-an-object-in-ruby). Ruby doesn't have a one-method way to perform deep copies, but that post describes how to use **marshalling** and **unmarshalling** to make a deep copy.

`clone` and `dup` work very similarly, but there are some differences. According to the docs:

### [Object#clone](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Object.html#method-i-clone)

> Produces a shallow copy of *obj*—the instance variables of *obj* are copied, but not the objects they reference. Copies the frozen and tainted state of *obj*. See also the discussion under [Object#dup](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Object.html#method-i-dup).

### [Object#dup](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Object.html#method-i-dup)

> Produces a shallow copy of *obj*—the instance variables of *obj* are copied, but not the objects they reference. dup copies the tainted state of *obj*. See also the discussion under [Object#clone](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Object.html#method-i-clone). In general, clone and dup may have different semantics in descendant classes. While clone is used to duplicate an object, including its internal state, dup typically uses the class of the descendant object to create the new instance.
>
> This method may have class-specific behavior. If so, that behavior will be documented under the #initialize_copy method of the class.

You can take a look at the [dup](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Object.html#method-i-dup) and [clone](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Object.html#method-i-clone) docs.

### Edit

While my answer probably gives what the OP was looking for, it is not strictly correct, with respect to the semantics of passing by reference or value. See the other answers and comments on this page for some more discussion. You can also look at the discussion in the comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1872110/is-ruby-pass-by-reference-or-by-value) and [this post](http://ryanverner.com/post/33837637667/ruby-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value) for more information.

Comment: I'd +2, seeing the latest edit which makes the answer perfect. But I can only do +1. ;-)

Comment: -1. This is just plain wrong. Ruby *is* pass-by-value. Always. No exceptions. No ifs. No buts. You can check that out yourself if you don't believe me: `def foo(bar) bar = 'reference' end; baz = 'value'; foo(baz); puts "Ruby is pass-by-#{baz}" # Ruby is pass-by-value`

Answer (score 2):

Tossing in a formal answer the original question, on top of @Michael's excellent answer:

> Is there a way to pass objects by value and not by reference in Ruby?

No. Absolutely not. Not possible. Really no, just forget it.

Or more precisely, if we nitpick on vocabulary, Ruby passes references to objects by value, and the passed objects are mutable as a result.

In Ruby, you must either:

1. Manually clone/dup inputs and outputs as needed (see Michael's answer); or
2. Assume that nobody will screw up the internals of your class should you ever decide to not do so.

Rubyists tend to pick option 2, because the internals are built that way (attr_reader, etc. return object state), because of performance reasons, and because creating deep copies of everything you return or manipulate is by no means trivial in practice.

---

Answering Jörg's comment:

```
def foo(bar) bar << ' is now mutated' end;
baz = 'Baz';
foo(baz);
puts baz # Baz is now mutated
```

---

Adding a further note/example on freezing, since this can give unexpected results as well:

```
foo = {foo: 'bar'}.freeze  # {:foo=>"bar"}
foo[:foo] += 'baz'         # RuntimeError: can't modify frozen Hash
foo[:foo] << 'baz'         # {:foo=>"barbaz"}
```

Comment: -1. This is just plain wrong. Ruby *is* pass-by-value. Always. No exceptions. No ifs. No buts. You can check that out yourself if you don't believe me: `def foo(bar) bar = 'reference' end; baz = 'value'; foo(baz); puts "Ruby is pass-by-#{baz}" # Ruby is pass-by-value`

Comment: @JörgWMittag: no… you are completely wrong. See my updated answer. Your example reassigns the reference held by bar.

Comment: Yes, it does, because that is the *definition* of pass-by-reference. Pass-by-reference means that the reference itself instead of the value it references is passed, which means that the reference itself (i.e. the variable) can be manipulated by the callee. In Ruby, it can't, ergo Ruby is pass-by-value.

Comment: What your example demonstrates is mutable state. I never claimed that Ruby was a purely functional language like Haskell. If you mutate an object, it is mutated. That's obvious.

Comment: Methinks that however correct you might be on paper, you're nitpicking on vocabulary here. If you take the time to re-read the OP's question, you'll note that he's wondering about whether there's a way to not pass mutable objects as argument, and both answers you downvoted correctly answer that there isn't — the objects can always be mutated unless you manually dup/clone them.

Answer (score 2):

Ruby *is* pass-by-value. Always. Here's a simple program which demonstrates that fact:

```
def foo(bar)
  bar = 'reference'
end

baz = 'value'

foo(baz)

puts "Ruby is pass-by-#{baz}"
# Ruby is pass-by-value
```

What you are seeing is simply shared mutable state: if an object is mutable, it can be mutated, and if that object is visible through multiple references, then that mutation will be visible through multiple references. Simple as that. It doesn't matter if you call me "Jörg" like my friends do or "son" like my mom does, if I cut my hair, *both* of you will see that.

If you don't want your objects to be mutated, you need to make them immutable. For example:

```
class Person
  attr_reader :name

  private

  attr_writer :name

  def initialize(name)
    self.name = name
  end
end

def get_name(obj)
  obj.name = "Bob"
  puts obj.name
end

jack = Person.new('Jack')

puts jack.name
# Jack

get_name(jack)
# NoMethodError: private method `name=' called for #<Person:0xdeadbeef081542 @name='Jack'>

puts jack.name
# Jack
```

Now, your `Person` objects can no longer be changed by other objects. However, note that objects referenced by your `Person` objects obviously can *still* be changed:

```
jack.name << ' the Ripper'

puts jack.name
# Jack the Ripper

jack.name.replace('Bob')

puts jack.name
# Bob
```

If you want to protect against *that*, you need to make sure that all the objects referenced by your `Person` objects are *also* immutable. For example like this:

```
class Person
  def initialize(name)
    self.name = name.freeze
  end
end

jack = Person.new('Jack)

jack.name << 'the Ripper'
# RuntimeError: can't modify frozen String
```

Now, your `Person` objects are *truly* immutable. (At least as "truly" as can be in a language with such powerful reflection capabilities as Ruby.)

Unfortunately, we have now done to someone else the very same thing we are trying to protect ourselves against: we are mutating *their* objects! In `Person#initialize`, we mutate the `String` that is passed in by `freeze`ing it. If the method that created the `Person` wants to do something else with the `String`, they are in for a nasty surprise:

```
name = 'Jack'

jack = Person.new(name)

name << ' the Ripper'
# RuntimeError: can't modify frozen String
```

We can fix that by making a copy of the `String` first, before `freeze`ing it:

```
class Person
  def initialize(name)
    self.name = name.dup.freeze
  end
end

name = 'Jack'

jack = Person.new(name)

name << ' the Ripper'
# => 'Jack the Ripper'
```