# Clone or duplicate the results array of Ruby's Scan method?

Tags: ruby

Suppose I pass the string "abcd" through Ruby's Scan method using the regular expression `/(a)|(b)/`. This would return an array:

```
>> results_orig = "abcd".scan(/(a)|(b)/)
#=> [["a", nil], [nil, "b"]]
```

Now, if I duplicate (.dup) or clone (.clone) this array,

```
>> results_copy = results_orig.dup
#=> [[["a", nil], [nil, "b"]]
```

and modify any element of this copy, the *original* array also gets modified!

```
>> results_copy[0][0]="hello"
#=> "hello"
>> results_copy
#=> [["hello", nil], [nil, "b"]]
>> results_orig
#=> [["hello", nil], [nil, "b"]]
```

This is strange, since, first, the arrays have different object IDs (`results_orig.object_id == results_copy.object_id` returns `false`), and, second, it does not happen if the array was **not** the product of the Scan method. To see the latter, consider the following example.

```
>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>> b = a.dup
>> b[0] = "hello"
>> a
#=> [1, 2, 3]
>> b
#=> ["hello", 2, 3]
```

My current solution is to run scan twice and catch each array in separate objects---that is, `r_orig = "abca".scan(/(a)|(b)/)" ; r_copy = "abca".scan(/(a)|(b)/)`. But this is going to be very inefficient when I have to scan hundreds of strings.

Is there a proper way to duplicate the array from Scan's results that I can then modify whilst leaving the original results array unharmed?

**Edit #1: I am running Ruby 2.0.0-p353 on Mac OS X 10.9.2.**

**Edit #2: It appears the issue exists when the array structure is nested... simple (single-level) arrays don't seem to have this problem. Corrected my example to reflect this.**

Comment: Cannot reproduce on ruby 2.0. What version of Ruby are you using?

Comment: @ArieShaw Ruby 2.0.0-p353 on Mac OS X 10.9.2

Comment: @ArieShaw My example was too simple for the problem... Seems to be an issue with nested arrays rather than Scan itself. Please see edited example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make a Deep copy. [Check out this article](http://ruby.about.com/od/advancedruby/a/deepcopy.htm) for more information. Essentially, you need to do

```
copied_array = Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(complex_array))
```

Code source: http://thingsaaronmade.com/blog/ruby-shallow-copy-surprise.html. Marshalling works for arrays, but not for every object. A more robust method to perform a Deep copy is in the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8206537/1126116).