# Instance variables of different objects are both being changed

Tags: ruby, object, instance-variables

I have a class that contains an array. This is an example class. `a` is an array

```
class Holder
  attr_accessor :a
end
```

I am trying to make a copy of an object and execute a function on its array. An example situation:

```
t = Holder.new
t.a = (1..9).to_a
t2= Holder.new
t2.a = t.a
t2.a[2]+=10
t2.a
# => [1, 2, 13, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
t.a
# => [1, 2, 13, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Both array in each object are effected. I don't know how to make them separate. I tried with `clone` and `dup` too.

```
dupt = t2.dup
dupt.a[8]+=10
dupt
# => #<Holder:0x007fb6e193b0a8 @a=[1, 2, 13, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 19]>
t2
# => #<Holder:0x007fb6e1962ba8 @a=[1, 2, 13, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 19]>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `dup` on the `Array`, **not** on your `Holder` object. `dup` will not create copies of all the sub-elements in the object you are trying to copy.

```
t2.a = t.a.dup
```

Comment: Fixed my test example, but thats not working on my actual project... thanks

Comment: In your actual project are there more elements inside of the `Array` that might need their own `dup` call? If so you will need a deep copy solution so that you don't have to call `dup` on every object manually. This might help http://stackoverflow.com/q/8206523/1241782

Comment: Heh yeah its a multidimensional array. The trick with marshal worked. Thanks again