# Why does adjusting one Hash value also change another value?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to adjust the values of the hash `info` for the key `"#{item} W/COUPON"`, without changing the values of `info` for the key `item`, which is what seems to be inadvertently happening. All of this is taking place within a nested hash.

```
hash_with_coupons[item] = info
hash_with_coupons[item][:count] = info[:count] - coupon_hash[:num] 
hash_with_coupons["#{item} W/COUPON"] = info
hash_with_coupons["#{item} W/COUPON"][:price] = coupon_hash[:cost]
hash_with_coupons["#{item} W/COUPON"][:count] = 1
```

After this code runs,

- `hash_with_coupons[item][:price] == coupon_hash[:cost]`
- `hash_with_coupons[item][:count] == 1`

But they were supposed to be the original price and `info[:count] - coupon_hash[:num]`, respectively.

Comment: Can you post more code, maybe showing the data structures you are building using the nested hash?

Comment: The best thing is to post enough code so that people can paste it into IRB and test it.

Comment: And if you are using overly complicated hash structures you might want to take a more object oriented approach and use classes, methods, etc.

Comment: I don't think readers will understand your question. (I don't.) I suggest you edit to show `coupon_hash` (`coupon_hash = { ... }`) and also show the hash you want to produce. That may take a few minutes, so I further suggest you delete the question, do the edit, then undelete. The longer you leave it up as is the more likely you'll get downvotes and/or votes to close.

Comment: After the first assignment, `hash_with_coupons[item]` and `info` refer to the same object. Therefore, `hash_with_coupons[item][:count] = ...` is equivalent to `info[:count] = ...`. You might want to assign a (deep) copy of `info` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your `#{item} W/COUPON` entry is modifying your `item` entry is you've handed both of them the same `info` object. That is, after the two key assignments, your hash looks like this:

```
{
  item               => info,
  "#{item} W/COUPON" => info
}
```

Looking at it this way, it's clear that modifying one value modifies the other, and in fact modifies the original `info` variable - they're all the same object. A simple way to make your `hash_with_coupons` values independent is to call `dup` on `info` as you do the assignment:

```
hash_with_coupons[item] = info.dup
hash_with_coupons["#{item} W/COUPON"] = info.dup
# Make modifications
```

Then each of your hash keys gets a *copy* of `info`. `dup` does what's called a *shallow copy*, making a new `Hash` object with the same values as the old one. This will work as long as your `info` hash values are simple, like `Fixnum`s, and not references to more hashes, arrays, etc. that you want to modify. Otherwise, you'll need a [deep copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8206523/how-to-create-a-deep-copy-of-an-object-in-ruby) or you'll run into the same problem you're having now, just one level deeper.

Since you're new, I'd recommend taking a different approach to better see which values are ending up in `hash_with_coupons`. Instead of assigning `info` and then modifying things inside your hash, assign brand new hashes with the data you want:

```
hash_with_coupons[item] = {
  price: info[:price],
  count: info[:count] - coupon_hash[:num]
}
hash_with_coupons["#{item} W/COUPON"] = {
  price: info[:price] - coupon_hash[:cost],
  count: 1
}
```

This guarantees that the values of `hash_with_coupons` are distinct objects, so you won't accidentally modify both when you change one. It also makes it very clear which values end up where, so you can easily see if you start sharing references again.