# Copy object without any pointers in Ruby

Tags: ruby, copy, greedy

I am trying to write a Greedy Algorithm for a certain problem. Simplified it looks like this:

There's an object called `Foo` with an randomized attribute called `value` and a method that changes this value `change_value` in a way that depends on an integer `input`

```
class Foo
  def initialize
    value = rand(1,10)
  end

  def change_value(input)
    #changes the value in a certain way
  end
end
```

Now the Greedy Algorithmus just gets the new `value` of `Foo` for all possible inputs and return the best `input`.

```
foo = Foo.new

best_value = 0
best_input = 0

(1..inputs).each do |k|
  temp_foo = foo.clone
  temp_foo.change_value(k)
  if temp_foo.value>best_value
    best_value = temp_foo.value
    best_input = k
  end
end

Foo.change_value(best_input)
```

The code works nearly as intended. The big problem is that the `change_value`-method within the each-funtion alters the `temp_foo` and the `foo`. What do I need to change to makes those objects completly dependent of each other? I also tried `.dub` by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think #clone or #dup won't work because they will share a reference to @value inside Foo.

In any case, you can do it more readably by changing `Foo#change_value` so it doesn't actually mutate the object but returns a copy:

```
class Foo
  def initialize(value = nil)
    @value = value || rand(10)
  end

  def change_value(input)
    # returns a new Foo instance
    Foo.new(@value + 1)
  end

  def value
    @value
  end
end
```

Because you're copying data in any case, using an immutable object (Value Object) is more general than some kind of deep clone.

Comment: Did it mostly this way in the end. Just added an optional parameter to the initalizer so that I can call on `foo` this: `foo_copy = Foo.new(foo.value)`

Answer (score 0):

I assume you assign value to the instance variable `@value` in `Foo#initialize` not the local variable `value`.

I also assume you don't have a simple primitive like in your code above but rather another object that contains a pointer, otherwise you most probably would not have such problem. In other words, I assume your `change_value` method makes an operation that relies on the `@value` pointer, such as `@value[key] = some_new_value` and not pure assignment, such as `@value = some_new_object`. When your object gets copied with `clone` or `dup`, that particular pointer is being copied, instead of the underlying structure, and therefore any calls to `temp_foo.change_value` will result in changes to `foo`'s underlying `@value`.

To avoid this, you need to duplicate the object `@value` refers to. There is a trick you can use with `Marshal`, as discussed in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8206523/how-to-create-a-deep-copy-of-an-object-in-ruby), but I recommend against it since it causes a great deal of overhead. Instead, I would define a `deep_dup` method, such as below:

```
class Foo
  def deep_dup
    # Either this
    @value = @value.dup

    # OR this, and define the method #deep_dup in the class of @value 
    # to dup its internal structure too:
    @value = @value.deep_dup
  end
end
```

Then instead of doing `temp_foo = foo.clone` do `temp_foo = foo.deep_dup`.