# Array is being modified during enumeration

Tags: ruby, variables

My situation is quite sophisticated, that's why I replaced original data with simple numbers. So, please, don't pay attention to very simple data and 'idiotic' if conditions. It's just an example. Also, please, ignore typos if there's any - original code has no typos.

I have array of hashes with elements like `my_hsh = {"numbers" => [1, 2, 3, 4], "n_count" => 4}`

What I need to do:

1. Loop through the parent array and select appropriate hashes,
2. add each such hash to the array `my_arr_nochange`,
3. loop through "numbers" in each such hash and add'em to `the_hash["numbers"]`,
4. add hashes without these numbers to `my_arr_updt`.

So the code:

```
the_hash = {"numbers" => []}
my_arr_updt = []
my_arr_nochange = []
array_of_hashes.each do |my_hsh|
  if my_hsh["n_count"] == 4
    my_arr_nochange << my_hsh
    updated_hsh = my_hsh
    my_hsh["numbers"].each do |num|
      if num == 2
        the_hash["numbers"] += [ num ]
        updated_hsh["numbers"] -= [ num ]
      end
    end
    my_arr_updt << updated_hsh
  end
end

return the_hash, my_arr_updt, my_arr_nochange
```

The problem is `my_arr_nochange` is being modified, so instead of getting the old state of my_hsh inside I get the new one. Like:

```
my_arr_updt
=> [{"numbers" => [1, 3, 4], "n_count" => 4}]
my_arr_nochange 
=> [{"numbers" => [1, 3, 4], "n_count" => 4}]
```

Tried splitting in different methods and using sub-variables. No result.

P.S.: If you could help with more appropriate title, I would appreciate that too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe your issue is `updated_hsh = my_hsh`.

This does not duplicate the hash. Any changes to `updated_hsh` will change `my_hsh` and vice versa.

Using [Object#clone](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Object.html#method-i-clone) or [Object#dup](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Object.html#method-i-dup) is a step in the right direction, but won't actually duplicate inner objects (the "numbers" arrays):

```
h1 = [{numbers: [1,2,3], n_count: 3}]
h2 = h1.map(&:clone)
h2[0][:numbers] << 4
h2[0][:n_count] += 1

h1
# => [{numbers: [1,2,3,4], n_count: 3}]
```

You can see that `n_count` was not altered in the original, but `numbers` was.

To get around this, you can use [Hash#deep_dup](https://apidock.com/rails/Hash/deep_dup). This method isn't available in Ruby core. It is part of Active Support which is required by Rails, and can easily be loaded to a plain Ruby program as well, if you require the gem.

```
require 'active_support/all'

h1 = [{numbers: [1,2,3], n_count: 3}]
h2 = h1.map(&:deep_dup)
h2[0][:numbers] << 4
h2[0][:n_count] += 1

h1
# => [{numbers: [1,2,3], n_count: 3}]
```

You can also implement `deep_dup` yourself, if you don't want to use active support. See [How to create a deep copy of an object in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8206537/2981429)

Another alternative is to manually build the inner hashes, like so:

```
h1 = [{numbers: [1,2,3], n_count: 3}]
h2 = h1.map do |hsh|
  {
    numbers: hsh[:numbers].clone,
    n_count: hsh[:n_count]
  }
end
```

Although `deep_dup` is more concise

Comment: Comprehensively! Thx!